# How long does it takes for google play to update similar apps listing inside my app page?

Tags: android, google-play

It is really so frustrating that there are no specific answers when it comes to how/when google-play updates it's information regarding listed apps.

I recently submitted an update for my game, and now it is a live, but for some reason I don't know about, google removed similar apps listing inside my game page,

Adding my game as a similar app to other apps/games will help a lot driving organic installers into my game, and now unfortunately I don't have that.

It has been 5 days since I update my game, and I don't know how long will it take for google-play team to update my similar-apps listing, 
link here : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=play.TheEgg

I couldn't find any information on the internet regarding this.

I hope you have more experience in this, maybe you can help.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know Google Play's algorithm/heuristic for listing your app, but in general, if you launch an Android app, you should view it as a drop in the ocean.  There are so many apps out there now, that statistically it isn't really possible for everyone's app to be very visible.  If you look at many mobile startups these days, they are driving user acquisitions using a ton of marketing expense, without which, they might not get traction.

Comment: within 1hr to 8hr generally

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to application development, as *how Google algorithms work* does not relate to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Things google considers while determining similar apps are Category of apps,Download numbers,Keywords in the title and description,Developer Size of the apk. They are doing some inbuilt alogorithm for all these things.

Comment: You are right @androidshisya, I think the problem with "google algorithm" it consider many many factors before doing the update.. I don't know why they over-complicate it, I hope if things were much simpler and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many factors to check for. Here is the list which, according to me, decides "similar apps" list inclusion,

1. Category
2. Store listing
3. Number of Downloads
4. Number of / Average ratings
5. Crash / ANR [Most important]
6. Time user spends on your app

I think apps with best user experience will only make it to this listing.